# Where is the cronfile located?

Tags: raspbian, python, cron

I am writing a python program to go on the raspberry pi. I am currently making an installation script that will as part of its installation process, add a line on cron so that it will automatically startup on bootup.

I need access to the whole file, not just adding a line at the end. As I want the ability to uninstall the program, which will in part remove the line in the crontab.

Comment: This question belongs on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  However, before you bother to do that I suggest you make some effort to do some basic research yourself; `cron` has been around for decades (the version used in Raspbian is I think older than the WWW) and is extensively documented.  I will give you a quick clue by citing the 3rd paragraph in `man crontab`: *"...system cron jobs in the /etc/cron.d/ directory"*.

Answer (score 8):

Like most Debian based systems, the crontab is stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

On a different note: Why are you trying to start your program using crontab? This is neither a good nor a standard practice.  If you're going through the effort of writing an installer, you should be using an init script so that the user has the ability to issue start/stop/restart commands as needed.

Comment: I think `/var/spool` is used for per-user crontabs.  The system jobs are in `/etc/cron.d` and also `/etc/cron.[hourly|daily|monthly]`.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I assumed the system crontab would have been stored as a user tab under root or something.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: When running `sudo crontab -e`, so for root, the crontab is stored here: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. Probably `/etc/cron*` is used for systemd only.